# How to make this CTE query print rows with 0 value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I have a CTE based query, to which I pass about 2600 4-tuple latitude/longitude values using joins - these latitude longitude 4-tuples have been ID tagged and held in a second table called coordinates. These top left and bottom right latitude / longitude values are passed into the CTE in order to display the amount of requests (hourly) made within those coordinates for given two timestamps).- I am able to get the total requests per day within the timestamps given, that is, the total count of user requests on every specified day. (E.g. user opts to see every Wednesday or Wednesday AND Thursday etc. - between hours 11:55 and 22:04 between dates January 1 and 31, 2012 for every latitude/longitude 4-tuples I pass.) But I cannot get the rows with zcount as 0 in the results, I only get the rows with zcount > 0. My query is as below: (a note to [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) if he sees this, I checked the chat room discussion about my previous question and set the `coordinates` values to `NOT NULL` due to you saying that the coordinates can be `null` by design, but I still have the same issue somehow. -though I may have gotten what you meant wrong since I was down with a bad case of fever back then-

```
WITH v AS (
   SELECT '2012-1-1 11:55:11'::timestamp AS _from -- provide times once
         ,'2012-1-31 22:02:21'::timestamp AS _to
   )
, q AS (
   SELECT c.coordinates_id
        , date_trunc('hour', t.calltime) AS stamp
        , count(*) AS zcount
   FROM   v
   JOIN   mytable t ON  t.calltime BETWEEN v._from AND v._to
                   AND (t.calltime::time >= v._from::time AND
                        t.calltime::time <= v._to::time) AND 
(extract(DOW from t.calltime) = 3)
   JOIN   coordinates c ON (t.lat, t.lon) 
                   BETWEEN (c.bottomrightlat, c.topleftlon)
                       AND (c.topleftlat, c.bottomrightlon)
   GROUP BY c.coordinates_id, date_trunc('hour', t.calltime)
   )
, cal AS (
   SELECT generate_series('2012-1-1 11:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '2012-1-31 23:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '1 hour'::interval) AS stamp)
SELECT q.coordinates_id, cal.stamp::date, sum(q.zcount) AS zcount
FROM   v, cal
LEFT   JOIN q USING (stamp)
WHERE  extract(hour from cal.stamp) BETWEEN extract(hour from v._from)
                                        AND extract(hour from v._to)
AND    extract(DOW from cal.stamp) = 3 
AND    cal.stamp >= v._from
AND    cal.stamp <= v._to
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

The output I get when I execute this query is basically like this (normally I have about 10354 rows returned excluding the rows with 0 zcount, just providing two coordinates for sake of similarity):

```
coordinates_id  | stamp      | zcount
1               ;"2012-01-04";      2
1               ;"2012-01-11";      3
1               ;"2012-01-18";      2
2               ;"2012-01-04";      2
2               ;"2012-01-11";      3
2               ;"2012-01-18";      2
```

However, it should be like this where all rows with zcount 0 should also be printed out along with rows that have nonzero zcounts -E.g. January 25 with zcount 0 for the two coordinates with ID 1 and 2 should also be printed in this small portion of example-:

```
coordinates_id  | stamp      | zcount
1               ;"2012-01-04";      2
1               ;"2012-01-11";      3
1               ;"2012-01-18";      2
1               ;"2012-01-25";      0
2               ;"2012-01-04";      2
2               ;"2012-01-11";      3
2               ;"2012-01-18";      2
2               ;"2012-01-25";      0
```

Updated version with zcount values way bigger than actual. -Also rows with 0 zcount still not showing-

```
WITH v AS (
   SELECT '2012-1-1 11:55:11'::timestamp AS _from -- provide times once
         ,'2012-1-31 22:02:21'::timestamp AS _to
   )
, q AS (
   SELECT c.coordinates_id
        , date_trunc('hour', t.calltime) AS stamp
        , count(*) AS zcount
   FROM   v
   JOIN   mytable t ON  t.calltime BETWEEN v._from AND v._to
                   AND (t.calltime::time >= v._from::time AND
                        t.calltime::time <= v._to::time) AND 
(extract(DOW from t.calltime) = 3)
   JOIN   coordinates c ON (t.lat, t.lon) 
                   BETWEEN (c.bottomrightlat, c.topleftlon)
                       AND (c.topleftlat, c.bottomrightlon)
   GROUP BY c.coordinates_id, date_trunc('hour', t.calltime)
   )
, cal AS (
   SELECT generate_series('2012-1-1 11:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '2012-1-31 23:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '1 hour'::interval) AS stamp)
, coordst AS ( 
   SELECT coordinates_id FROM coordinates)
SELECT q.coordinates_id, cal.stamp::date, COALESCE(sum(q.zcount),0) AS zcount
FROM   v, coordst, cal
LEFT   JOIN q USING (stamp)
WHERE  extract(hour from cal.stamp) BETWEEN extract(hour from v._from)
                                        AND extract(hour from v._to)
AND    extract(DOW from cal.stamp) = 3 
AND    cal.stamp >= v._from
AND    cal.stamp <= v._to
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a distinct list of coordinates_id to perform a proper CROSS JOIN. 
1. Add another entry in the WITH.
2. Add it to your JOIN (FROM v,cal, coords).
3. Your zcount will show NULL, so COALESCE it.

```
WITH v AS (
   SELECT '2012-1-1 11:55:11'::timestamp AS _from -- provide times once
         ,'2012-1-31 22:02:21'::timestamp AS _to
   )
, q AS (
   SELECT c.coordinates_id
        , date_trunc('hour', t.calltime) AS stamp
        , count(*) AS zcount
   FROM   v
   JOIN   mytable t ON  t.calltime BETWEEN v._from AND v._to
                   AND (t.calltime::time >= v._from::time AND
                        t.calltime::time <= v._to::time) AND 
(extract(DOW from t.calltime) = 3)
   JOIN   coordinates c ON (t.lat, t.lon) 
                   BETWEEN (c.bottomrightlat, c.topleftlon)
                       AND (c.topleftlat, c.bottomrightlon)
   GROUP BY c.coordinates_id, date_trunc('hour', t.calltime)
   )
, cal AS (
   SELECT generate_series('2012-1-1 11:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '2012-1-31 23:00:00'::timestamp
                        , '1 hour'::interval) AS stamp)
, coordst AS ( 
   SELECT DISTINCT coordinates_id FROM coordinates)
SELECT coordst.coordinates_id, cal.stamp::date, COALESCE(sum(q.zcount),0) AS zcount
FROM   v CROSS JOIN coordst CROSS JOIN cal
LEFT   JOIN q USING q.stamp = cal.stamp AND coordst.coordinates_id = q.coordinates_id
WHERE  extract(hour from cal.stamp) BETWEEN extract(hour from v._from)
                                        AND extract(hour from v._to)
AND    extract(DOW from cal.stamp) = 3 
AND    cal.stamp >= v._from
AND    cal.stamp <= v._to
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Comment: I added a `coords AS (SELECT coordinates_id FROM coordinates ORDER BY coordinates_id ASC)`, changed the `FROM` above the `JOIN` to `FROM v, cal, coords` but when I run it, now I get the `ERROR:  column "stamp" specified in USING clause does not exist in left table` message. -Also, I coalesced the zcount by `COALESCE(sum(q.zcount),0) AS zcount` in my final `SELECT` statement

Comment: The USING is suppose to use the prior resultset. It's probably just a progresssql bug, flip the coords and cal in your FROM.

Comment: I did and it works now but the results are erroneous. Instead of getting the output I specified in my question, I get zcount values way bigger than they should be -also I still can't see the rows with 0 zcount and the query took a lot longer to finish-, I edited the question with your solution proposal, can you take another look?

Comment: 1. put DISTINCT in your coords sub-query. 2. change your FROM to v CROSS JOIN coordst CROSS JOIN cal LEFT JOIN q ON q.stamp = cal.stamp AND coordst.coordinates_id = q.coordinates_id. 3. the 0 zcount is there, you just skipped it because you are using q (which is null) as source of coordinates_id, use coordst, instead.

Comment: Done, thank you very much for your help. Are there any points where you would suggest I tune in my query? I get the results in about 35 seconds if the timespan is a month like in this question but I would like to look for larger timespans and -possibly- a bigger coordinates table -like about 1 million rows of coordinates- in the future.

Comment: Assuming that the coordinates table is a lot smaller in size, you can roll up mytable first before joining. v is not necessary in your main join but it's contribution to run time is insignificant. You can only improve on q.